# How to get Ruby Dir#glob to return basenames, not absolute_paths?

Tags: ruby, absolute-path, dir

`FakeProfilePictures::Photo.all_large_names_2x` (defined below) returns an array of absolute path names, but when I do `Dir["picture_*@2x.*"]` from the correct directory in `irb`, I only get the basenames (what I want). What's the best way to get the base names? I know I could do it by adding `.map { |f| File.basename(f) }` as shown in the comment, but is there an easier/[better/faster/stronger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLYD_-A_X5E) way?

```
module FakeProfilePictures
  class Photo
    DIR = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "photos"))

    # ...

    def self.all_large_names_2x
      @@all_large_names_2x ||= Dir[File.join(DIR, "picture_*@2x.*")] # .map { |f| File.basename(f) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do

```
Dir.chdir(DIR) do
  Dir["picture_*@2x.*"]
end
```

after the block, the original dir is restored.

Comment: Nice. `@@all_large_names_2x ||= Dir.chdir(DIR) { Dir["picture_*@2x.*"] }` worked! Thanks! I think I'll go with that cause it's less code and probably faster? Who knows...

Answer (score 3):

You could `chdir` into `DIR` before globbing, but I would just run everything through `basename`.

Comment: Why? What about @J-_-L's solution above? I think I prefer that.